# How to keep x and y-axis equal with a colorbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been able to use `scatter` to plot `x`, `y`, and `z`, with the latter being the color-coded variables defined by a `colorbar`. However, whenever I introduce the `colorbar` it affects the aspect-ratio of the axes in the sense that it "steals space" from the x-axis. Even if I define the `figsize`.

```
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('viridis')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[6, 6])

for dat_x, dat_b, dat_c in zip([data_x1, data_x2, data_x3], [data_y1, data_y2, data_y3], [data_z1, data_z2, data_z3]):
    for dx, dy, dz in zip(dat_x, dat_b, dat_c):
        sc = ax.scatter(dx, dy, dz, cmap=cm, norm=mplcol.LogNorm(vmin=1, vmax=200, s=100)

sc = plt.colorbar(sc)

plt.show()
```

How can I keep the length of the x-axis and the y-axis equal while simultaneously prevent the `colorbar` from "stealing space" from the x-axis?

Comment: Try adjusting the [aspect ratio](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html). Depending on your data, `ax.set_aspect('equal')` or `ax.set_aspect('equal', 'box')`might work.

Comment: `plt.colorbar` steals space from the axes, that's how it's designed. However, it provides a `cax` argument, which can be used to supply an axes for the colorbar to reside in. You can use it to supply some axes you created for that purpose and which does not steal any space.